# visual Foxpro releasing form without executing remaining code

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have an old application built in Visual Foxpro 9. I want to terminate the form without executing remaining code. Form.Release event release the form after executing remaining code in event it called from. I want to use this when any error occurred, can anyone please help?

I may have other forms open and dont want to close other forms in event of error on one form. Cancel would close all open forms, so I cant use it.

Comment: Are you asking how to use "on error" command (or form.error)?

Comment: I know how to use on error and form.error but I want to know how do I close the form when error occurs. In my application I have multiple forms may be opened at same time so if something goes wrong on one one form (e.g. method not found, table not found, etc...) I want to log this error in user's activity table and close that form only and keep other forms open. Cancel would close all open forms and quit from the application which I want to prevent. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know how to use "on error" then why wouldn't you use it? I will give a rough sample (it will be greatly simplified just for sampling).

Answer (score 1):

> Main.Prg

```
On Error Do ErrHandle With Error( ), Message( ), Program( ), Lineno( )

Do Form form1
Do Form form2
Do form formN
Read Events


Procedure ErrHandle(tnerror, tcMessage, tcProg, tnLineNo)
    Local lcError
    TEXT to m.lcError textmerge noshow
Error No: << m.tnerror >>. Message: << m.tcMessage >>
Source: << m.tcProg >> at line << m.tnLineNo >>
    ENDTEXT
    Messagebox(m.lcError, 0+4096, "Error", 5000)
    Local loForm
    loForm = _vfp.ActiveForm
    If !Isnull(m.loForm)
        m.loForm.Release()
    Endif
Endproc
```

This would just release the active form.

Comment: No this does not work. Lets say have on form2 I have button and in click event I have 50 lines of code, If I get error on line#20, Errhandle will be called and it continues execution from line#21 and THEN form will be released. In my case I dont want to execute code after it hits error.

Comment: @mak101, it was just the general idea. You can narrow it to a particular method too. I will add as another answer just not to clutter this one.

Answer (score 0):

> Main.prg

```
Do Form form1
Do Form form2
Do form formN
Read Events
```

> Errhandle.prg

```
lparameters tnerror, tcMessage, tcProg, tnLineNo
Local lcError
TEXT to m.lcError textmerge noshow
Error No: << m.tnerror >>. Message: << m.tcMessage >>
Source: << m.tcProg >> at line << m.tnLineNo >>
ENDTEXT
Messagebox(m.lcError, 0+4096, "Error", 5000)
```

> Form method where error is expected:

```
Local loForm
loForm = thisform
On Error ;
  return ErrHandle(Error( ), Message( ), Program( ), Lineno( )) ;
         and m.loForm.Release()
local lc
lc = "Hello"
If m.lc = 1 && explicit error


EndIf

_screen.Caption = "This code wouldn't run"
On Error
```

Note: This is sort of using try ... catch blocks. I personally don't use try ... catch because unlike on error it doesn't catch all errors.

Comment: Thanks @Cetin for your quick response but as I said it does not stop executing remaining code. I tried separating ErrHanle.prg but it still executing remaining code after executing code in ErrHanle.prg :(

Comment: @mak101, are you sure. Actually I tested the last code before sending and it doesn't on my system.

Comment: Instead _screen.Caption I put messagebox("Should not be run this line") and it hit the code :(

Comment: @mak101, That is strange. I just tested with messagebox() too and it didn't run. If you want to see overly simplified project I have used, I can email it to you if I know your address. (and I actually use this approach in production too).

Comment: Please send me and let me see what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mak101, If you give me your email address I can send it tomorrow.

Comment: please send it to me on mak102 at live

Answer (score 0):

On the Form's Error event place the following code:

---

LPARAMETERS nError, cMethod, nLine

*Handle the error/ clean up/ MessageBox / Log error to file or table / etc.

thisform.release

RETURN TO MASTER

---

** Hope this helps